# Kubuntu installation failed (dual boot) and I can't access any operating system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu, windows-10

I tried a dual boot with Windows 10 and Kubuntu. My BIOS mode was "Legacy". I prepared the free space to install Kubuntu. I made sure to use that space to create the /, /boot, /home partitions etc. I had a message asking to create an EFI partition, so I did it and assigned it 1GB. The installation process failed: it had a "fatal error" that said "unable to install GRUB in dev/sda". It restarted and opened what I think was Kubuntu Live or Kubuntu test, with a shortcut on the desktop that said "Install Kubuntu". I repeated the steps again and same error. The problem is that now I can't access any operating system. The PC boots, appears logo of my ASUS BIOS, black screen with the _ line and then enters the BIOS automatically. Setting boot priority for my hard drive does not change this loop. I am afraid I have corrupted the boot of my Windows. I can only access the Kubuntu installation media via my USB.

Excuse my English, I'm using a translator.

Comment: It would be very unusual for Windows 10 to use legacy - so you may have a situation where Kubuntu is trying to install in legacy and Windows is in uefi. Try charging back to uefi and see if Windows will boot?

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: https://pastebin.com/jQa9FBSP